# How to use data-attributes in a generic way?

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute, advanced-custom-fields

Having this code below It would work to create data-attributes for a given set of "own fields" in the advanced custom fields-plugin

```
if ($use_acf === true) {
    $fields_cpt = get_fields( $id );
    if ( $fields_cpt === false ) {
        $this->errormessage = 'value of custom type fields is not found';
        add_action( 'admin_notices', array( $this,'error_notice' ) ); 
        return;
    }
    $field_name = $fields_cpt['municipality_name'];
    $field_phone = $fields_cpt['municipality_phone'];
    $field_link = $fields_cpt['municipality_link'];

    $html .= '<option data-fname="' . $field_name . '" data-fphone="' . $field_phone.' " data-flink="'. $field_link . '"  value="' . $id . '">' . $title . '</option>';      
}
```

And in JS it would look something like this...

```
var selected_row = $(this).find(":selected");
var fname = selected_row.data('fname');           
var fphone = selected_row.data('fphone');
var flink = selected_row.data('flink');
```

but I want a more general approach where there can be unknown number of fields and they should be named to whatever...

How do I achieve that? I was thinking of json, but it seems that data-attribute does not support json-format. Using ajax is not an option for me in this case.

**UPDATE**
Clarification

Instead of

```
var selected_row = $(this).find(":selected");
var fname = selected_row.data('fname');           
var fphone = selected_row.data('fphone');
var flink = selected_row.data('flink');
```

I would like to do something like this in js:

```
var selected_row = $(this).find(":selected");
var cptvalues = selected_row.data('cptfieldvalues');
```

and in html something like this...

```
<option data-cptfieldvalues="{municipality_name:actual name, municipality_phone: actual phone, municipality_link: actual link}">name of municipality</option>
```

Comment: can you may post some sample what you trying to achieve? Actually its kind of hard to understand what exactly you want. At least for me. Or am I right if I say you want to have some kind of .data array that contains all data names ?

Comment: @Dwza - I've updated the question. Hope it clarifies what I want..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dataset` method available in javascript to take all the data attributes on the target element and it returns an object which contains all the data attributes:

```js
var list = document.querySelector('h1').dataset;

document.querySelector('#log').innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(list) + '</pre>';
```

```html
<h1 data-fname="FirstName" data-fphone="F-Phone" data-flink="FLink!!!">Test with three data attributes.</h1>

<div id='log'></div>
```

---

So within your code you can do just this:

```
var selected_row = $(this).find(":selected");
var data = selected_row[0].dataset; // it will return you all the data attributes.
```

Comment: hahaha, that's nice.. I was testing around and jut build a js function that achives actually the same.. but obviously the implemented this already :D

Answer (score 1):

Now it took me some time because I never heard about `dataset` what actually this what op wanted. So Jai's answere is truly the right one...

But this is an alternative way to do it.

```js
var e = document.getElementById("xy");
var dataObj = {};

for (var i = 0, attr = e.attributes, n = attr.length; i < n; i++){
    if(attr[i].nodeName.indexOf("-")){
        var attr_split = attr[i].nodeName.split("-");
        if(attr_split[0] == "data"){
            dataObj[attr_split[1]] = attr[i].nodeValue;
        }
    }
}

alert(JSON.stringify(dataObj));
```

```html
<div id="xy" data-aaa="111" data-bbb="222" data-ccc="333">Div was created by php</div>
```